# Identify if PHP_CodeSniffer is Sniffing an abstract (or final) class

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I'm writing a Sniff in PHP_CodeSniffer for checking class names, and my abstract class names have some different naming requirements to non-abstract classes.

How can I identify if current Sniff is sniffing an abstract class or not?

Comment: If you're implementing your own sniff - the `abstract` keyword will be in the tokens stream.

Comment: What do you currently have? Are you implementing your own sniff?

Comment: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.coding-standard-tutorial.php ?

Comment: It is the "The Token Stack" section. Read it and check some bundled sniffs.

Comment: Well, I clearly see the "abstract" in the token stream: http://ideone.com/pH4DG8 "Have I not jumped through enough hoops yet for my question to be answered?" --- your question is **TOO VAGUE**. `abstract` **IS** in the token stream. You provided NOTHING for what you currently have. "found nothing useful" --- is not useful, see the link - it **IS THERE**.

Comment: I spent couple more minutes and found example in the phpcs source: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/blob/master/CodeSniffer%2FStandards%2FPSR2%2FSniffs%2FClasses%2FClassDeclarationSniff.php

Comment: Please provide the source class, the corresponding token stream and the sniff (since I cannot see how it's possible for a token to not be presented in the stream). Also please check the links in both my comments. "My question is too vague?" --- it is. "How can I identify if current Sniff is sniffing an abstract class or not?" --- check if the `abstract` token is in the token stream.

Comment: "You've spent more time in comments than it would have taken just to provide an answer" --- the answer was provided in the very first comment, 2 hours ago :-S Is this correct to use, and reliable?" --- It is (if you also want to check if it's `final`). "Please don't tell me to RTFM to find out" --- I never did - I always provided the accurate links to what you exactly asked.

Comment: @zerkms thanks for the help. I've deleted my comments here as they only got us to the answer and don't really add anything of value to anyone else viewing this Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms) for pointing me in the right direction.

To check if the current Sniff is reading an `abstract` or `final` class, use the following code:

```
if (in_array(
  $tokens[($stackPtr - 2)]['code'], 
  array(T_ABSTRACT, T_FINAL)
) === true 
) {
  // TRUE - class is abstract or final
} else {
  // FALSE - class is NOT abstract or final
}
```

Removing either `T_ABSTRACT` `T_FINAL` would remove the check for that type.

i.e. Without the `T_ABSTRACT` in the code above, it would return FALSE for an `abstract` class, and still TRUE for a `final` class.

You will also need this following code in the class, in order for the above code to work:

```
$tokens = $phpcsFile->getTokens();
```

I have tested the above code and it works as I have outlined in this answer.
With the limited info on the internet at present for PHP_CodeSniffer, hopefully this will help someone else.

Feel free to suggest edits or edit this answer.